# What is this vector problem asking to find, the magnitude of the force F or the component of it that goes along the ramp?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, acceleration, vectors

A shopper pushes a 7.5-kg shopping cart up a 13 (degree)incline. Find the magnitude of the horizontal force, F, needed to give the cart an acceleration of 1.41 m/s$^2$.

I ask this because the solution to this problem is $7.5[1.41 + 9.81\sin(13)] = 27.1$, which describes the component of the force along the direction of the ramp.

However, the question explicitly states to find the magnitude of the "horizontal" force, which sounds to me a lot like its asking for the entire magnitude of the force, not just a component of it. The answer in that case would be, $\sqrt{27.1^2 + 7.5\cdot9.81\cos(13)} = 76.7$, would it not? Yet, this answer is not the one shown in the solutions.

Comment: horizontal means parallel to the horizon, not to the ramp.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean. So why is the answer the component of the force that is parallel to the ramp?

Comment: The answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the directions **up** the ramp and **perpendicular** to the ramp as the simplest coordinate system.

Find the component of the **vertical** force of gravity that acts **down** the ramp.

Find the component of the **horizontal** force F that acts **up** the ramp.

Find an expression for the **net** force up the ramp, and equate to the mass of the cart times the acceleration of the cart **up** the ramp.  Solve for F.

Comment: Thank you, the correct answer was 28. Just one more question though, why doesn't sqrt[(net force-Mgcos(13))^2 + MgSin^2(13)] yield this answer as well?